# `block (2 levels) in package_helper': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano, rubber

I'm trying to host my first app using ec2 and `rubber`.

While running `cap rubber:create_staging` I got this error:

```
rubber/recipes/rubber/setup.rb:635:in `block (2 levels) in package_helper': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The error is internal to the gem, but I'm not sure if I did something to cause it.

Previously I had a problem with the AMI. Provided as the default in `rubber.yml` was

`image_type: c1.medium
 image_id: ami-90c574f8`

But something wasn't working with that so I went to the recommended website and got:

`image_type: t2.micro
image_id: ami-12a3247a`

Although I didn't launch the instance from the Amazon console it seemed to work fine.

Also, when asked for `Hostname to use for staging instance [production]:` I got it confused with the default domain `foo` (I realized my mistake immediately) and so now I have `foo.foo.com` all over the place. I tried changing it to `foo.com` in `etc/hosts` and `.ssh/known_hosts`but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same bug and saw your issue on github for rubber. I figured out what could have been a possible reason. See my issue:

https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/546

Comment: Oh, cool but I actually quit trying to handle hosting myself and went with a PaaS. But good to know that I wasn't crazy or TOTALLY incompetent.